# Why trait does not work in abstract class?

Tags: php, abstract-class, traits

A trait work incorrectly if is used in abstract class.

Consider the following code:

```
abstract class C {
    static $class;

    use T;
}

trait T {
    static $mockClass;

    public function __construct() {
        static::$mockClass = static::$class;
    }
}

class A extends C{
    static $class = 'A1';
}

class B extends C{
    static $class = 'B1';
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

dump($a::$mockClass); // B1, should be A1
dump($b::$mockClass); // B1, should be B1
```

You se that when dumping `mockClass` we have `B1` in both cases. Why? When I do not extend from `C` and use the trait directly I have expected result.

I can not find any information about the specific usage of traits in abstract classes. Can anyone explain me why my code does not work as I expect?

Comment: Think it's more to do with using `static` properties than traits.

Comment: @NigelRen I did not understand. What do you mean?

Comment: @FreeLightman, did you see my answer? Does it explain you why your code does not work as you expected?

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski partitially. I have understood that before you answered. But it is like a bug in php. If I wanted so that `$mockClass` was tied to `C` I would use `self` which is designed for this. But I have no way to assign a value to inherited static prop in `A` because it is referred to `C` so it just duplictes `self`. The one way to solve this is to define static prop in inherited classes `A` and `B`. But I have a parent class which should do this for me

Comment: Yes, I was quite surprised also when I realized that (read about that in a book of Matt Zandstra "Php - objects, patterns and practice") and in examples which came with that knowledge there were examples always redeclaring variables/functions which should be used based of the keyword `static`. Because Im not so sure about analogous behavior in other languages it is hard to discuss about different possible implementation of those funcionality, also I guess after all it is not a bug but just implication coming from the way how language is designed.

Comment: Also it is very comon that our vision of how particular functionality of language should work is different from how it really works :) After thinking about it more I realized that it might not really be undesirable behaviour, because if you use the keyword `self` instead of `static` you explicitly deprive inheriting classes of possibility to get use this functionality but if you use `static` you make it an option for them to use it. So you see now it is not definitely a bug ;)

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski You see that `static` does not work as it should. So what optionality are you saying about? `self` is good sometimes. I used a couple of times. But static seems to me a little buggy. My example is the example of this.

Comment: No, I just made big two comments to explain my view about that, Im definitely not saying that static is buggy - it is just different from what you would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, this is more to do with `static` properties.  Static properties are shared between all of the instances of a class (which is why you can't use `$this` to refer to them.) As all of your classes extend C, they all will share the same value of `$mockClass`.  You would find that all instances will have the last value assigned to `$mockClass`, if you swapped the creation of the two objects `$a` and `$b` round, both will display `A1`.

A working version, using normal properties...

```
trait T {
    public $mockClass;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mockClass = static::$class;
    }
}

abstract class C {
    static $class;

    use T;
}

class A extends C{
    static $class = 'A1';
}

class B extends C{
    static $class = 'B1';
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

print_r($a->mockClass); // A1, should be A1
print_r($b->mockClass); // B1, should be B1
```

I would like to add that having a constructor in a trait is bound to cause problems at some point, so not the best thing to start using.

Update:
As already mentioned, all of your classes extend C which uses the trait T, if you moved the `use T;` to the derived classes A & B...

```
abstract class C {
    static $class;
}

trait T {
    static $mockClass;

    public function __construct() {
        static::$mockClass = static::$class;
    }
}

class A extends C{
    static $class = 'A1';
    use T;
}

class B extends C{
    static $class = 'B1';
    use T;
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

print_r($a::$mockClass); // A1, should be A1
print_r($b::$mockClass); // B1, should be B1
```

Still don't think this is a good use of traits, but I will leave that up to you.

Comment: I know about static propertis. You completely changed the design (replaced instance props with instance ones). And did not explain why my way does not work. It's like a workaround. But not an answer.

Comment: Sorry - thought 'Static properties are shared between all of the instances of a class' was the answer to your problem. As all of your classes extend C, they all will share the same value of `$mockClass`.

Comment: Actually I need the question why the code does not work. And what to do so that it would work while being too close to what my source code is. If my code is not valid or incorrect - just say. But workaround is a ultimate variant.

Comment: As to your edit. I did say that using traits directly solves the problem.

Comment: The way you have your existing will not work at all, I have tried to explain why and how you can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code does not work as you expect is this:

During instantiation of A: `$a = new A();`,

this part of code is executed: `static::$mockClass = static::$class;`

where `static::$class` has value of `'A1'` and obviously comes from class `A`, **BUT**

until `$mockClass` is not redeclared in child class, it resides in class `C`.

Even when you use the keyword `static::` **because** this specific part of code `static::$mockClass = static::$class;` which is responsible for instantiation is executed in class `C`.

The most important part which you seem to not understand is: in PHP (I'm not sure about other languages) when some part of code is defined in class A and class B inherits from class A and has additional part of code - if you execute any part of code on B, which was not redefined in B but comes for A - you can imagine that the code is in fact executed in parent class A where it comes from.

So when next time during instantiation of B the code `static::$mockClass = static::$class;` executes again - `static::$class` has now value of `'B1'` but overrides value of `static::$class` which still resides in `C`.

This slightly changed your code example should make you understand what is happening (and it works as expected):

```
abstract class C {
    static $class;

    use T;
}

trait T {
    static $mockClass;

    public function __construct() {
        static::$mockClass = static::$class;
    }
}

class A extends C{
    static $class = 'A1';
    static $mockClass;
}

class B extends C{
    static $class = 'B1';
    static $mockClass;
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

var_dump($a::$mockClass); // A1, should be A1
var_dump($b::$mockClass); // B1, should be B1
```

Comment: You can also ask why then `static::$class` does not come from `C` and why it is not null then. The answer obviously is: the language is constructed that way.